# Detener un bucle for anidado tras detectar una condición

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, bucles

Tengo una duda posiblemente bastante básica pero que me esta rompiendo la cabeza. La cuestión es que entiendo que cuando alguien quiere detener un bucle for simple puede hacer uso de la sentencia break, pero en la siguiente situación con dos bucles for anidados necesito salir completamente de ambos bucles cuando se detecte la primera pareja de números repetida.

El tema esta en que cuando imprimo el valor de firstIndex, la variable que mostrara el indice del array en el que se encuentra el numero repetido (el indice, no el valor, de ahí el uso de i -1) me muestra el indice de la segunda pareja que se repite, no de la primera, lo cual me hace pensar que aquí el uso de break (el cual me han dicho que es imprescindible en este ejercicio en concreto) provoca la salida del segundo bucle for pero acaba volviendo al primero y terminando toda la serie.

Testeando los valores de i y j en cada iteración con console.log veo que efectivamente eso es lo que ocurre.

```js
        var arrWithNumbers = [1,2,3,4,3,6,7,8,7,10];
        var firstIndex = undefined;
    
        for (i=0; i < arrWithNumbers.length; i++){
        
         for (j=0; j < arrWithNumbers.length; j++){
    
              if (i !== j && arrWithNumbers[i] === arrWithNumbers[j]){
    
                firstIndex = arrWithNumbers[i] -1;
    
    
                break;
    
            }
        }
    }
    
    console.log(firstIndex);
```

Answer (score 3):

Puedes crear un flag que indique cuando quieres salir, e incluirlo en el condicional del bucle.

```js
var arrWithNumbers = [1,2,3,4,3,6,7,8,7,10];
var firstIndex = undefined;
var solucionado=false;
for (i=0; i<arrWithNumbers.length&&!solucionado; i++){
  for (j=0; j < arrWithNumbers.length&&!solucionado; j++){
    if (i !== j && arrWithNumbers[i] === arrWithNumbers[j]){
      firstIndex = arrWithNumbers[i] -1;
      solucionado=true;
    }
  }
}
console.log(firstIndex);
```

Ahora bien, tu código es mejorable, por ejemplo, el segundo bucle puede empezar a continuación del primero, para no repetir comparaciones, y como resultado debes usar el indice (i), que el valor-1 corresponda en este caso es pura coincidencia.

```js
var arrWithNumbers = [1,2,3,4,3,6,7,8,7,10];
var firstIndex = undefined;
var solucionado=false;
for (i=0; i < arrWithNumbers.length-1 && !solucionado; i++){
  for (j=i+1 ; j < arrWithNumbers.length && !solucionado; j++){
    if (arrWithNumbers[i] === arrWithNumbers[j]){
      firstIndex = i;
      solucionado=true;
    }
  }
}
console.log(firstIndex);
```

Answer (score -2):

Puedes hacer algo tan simple como esto:

```
var arrWithNumbers = [1,2,3,4,3,6,7,8,7,10];
var firstIndex = undefined;

for (i=0; i < arrWithNumbers.length; i++){
  for (j=0; j < arrWithNumbers.length; j++){
    if (i !== j && arrWithNumbers[i] === arrWithNumbers[j]){
      firstIndex = arrWithNumbers[i] -1;
      i = arrWithNumbers.length;
    }
  }
}

console.log(firstIndex);
```

Notaras que lo unico que hice fue romper la primera condición del primer bucle, lo iguale al largo del arreglo y esto hace que salga inmediatamente del bucle.

Ejecuta el código y notaras que encuentra el indice del elemento repetido.